# How to get possible combinations of elements by adding two elements from list

Tags: python, arrays, list, tuples, combinations

If list is [4,3,2,5]

so pairs will be (43, 25), (3, 245), (53, 24)

As they are combination of pairs of every element of list

My question is, How to get above pairs for general list of these pairs?

Comment: can you explain your pair formation in more clarity and provide more example

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description, but that doesn't tell us what _problem_ you're having. What have you tried, and what troubles did you encounter? Please [edit] your post to include a [valid question](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know what is [on-topic](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic); asking us to write the program for you, suggestions, and external links are off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each permutation of the original list, take each partition. That would look something like:

```
from itertools import permutations

l = [4,3,2,5]

def combos(l):
    for p in permutations(l):
        p = "".join(map(str, p))
        yield from ((int(p[:n]), int(p[n:])) for n in range(1, len(p)))
        
list(combos(l))
```

Which results in:

```
[(4, 325),
 (43, 25),
 (432, 5),
 (4, 352),
 (43, 52),
 (435, 2),
 (4, 235),
 (42, 35),
 (423, 5),
 (4, 253),
 (42, 53),
 (425, 3),
 ...
 (524, 3),
 (5, 234),
 (52, 34),
 (523, 4)]
```